# delete particular row in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i just started with angular.i checked few links stackoverflow links but none worked in my case.i have table where i am adding rows dynamically and i also need to delete rows dynamically but  my code deleting rows from the last row even i am clicking delete button of some other row.i used below code and i am giving stackblitz link below. thanks in advance.

```js
  rows = [1];
    
addrows() {
      this.rows.push(1);
 }

deleterow(row){
  this.rows.splice(row, 1);
}
```

```html
 <table>
 <tr *ngFor="let row of rows;">
 <td> something</td>
 <td> something</td>
 <td> something</td>
 <td>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleterow(i)">Delete</button>
 </td>
<tr>
<table>
<div class="text-center">       
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addrows()">ADD more rows</button>
</div>
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhytp1)

Comment: Your stackblitz link is broken. Please add more code to the question to show where `i` comes from and how `deleteRow` is called

Comment: please check now its working

Comment: Thanks. You should still add more code to your question to demonstrate your problem though.

Comment: And please don't use angularjs tags on angular questions. I've removed the tag

Comment: I am adding more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the row's index to splice the row. You are currently just hoping that a variable `i` gets magically created.

In my solution's component.ts, I am going to allow my HTML to add to and delete from a simple array.

component.ts

```
counter: number = 0;

rows = [];

addRow() {
  this.counter++;
  this.rows.push(this.counter);
}

deleteRow(row: number) {
  this.rows.splice(row, 1);
}
```

The key to the `deleteRow` function is that you need access to the current index within `*ngFor`. For that, you can use `let i = index` within the `*ngFor` to store the current index in a variable `i`.

component.html

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
    <td>{{row}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="deleteRow(i)">Delete row</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button (click)="addRow()">Add row</button>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7uwuye

Comment: thanks but initially at least one row should be there in the page

Comment: The question is about how to delete rows, and this answers that? It's the simplest exercise to modify my example to initialise it with a row. I've updated my stackblitz

Comment: yes, I figured it out. can you please tell how can I store each row data in the form of an array of objects.

Comment: That's definitely a separate question

Comment: unfortunately yes but the internet doesn't have enough resources for this problem to solve my own.

Comment: Angular is extremely well documented with a very large presence on StackOverflow. And by "another question", I literally meant that it's best as another StackOverflow question if you cannot find your answer on the whole of the internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208309/discussion-between-prem-and-kurt-hamilton).

Comment: The first 3 links I found. I'm pretty sure there's some useful stuff in these, and should at least give you an idea of your approach to a dynamic form. https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/ https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-acf61b4a2afe https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example

Comment: I can't chat now. Hopefully those links will help get you started though

Answer (score -2):

Javascript

`deleterow(id){
  document.getElementById("row"+id).remove();
}`

HTML

`<td id="row1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleterow(1)">Delete</button>
 </td>`

Comment: You should avoid manipulating the DOM directly in Angular. Angular is model-based, and the solution to this question is well suited to typical Angular methods.